# Why can I not concatenate Integer.toBinaryString() to another string in Java?

Tags: java, string-concatenation, bin

I'm trying to convert integer inputs into binary string and concatenate them together into one long string. Example:

```
input: 4 5
output: 0100 0101
```

After checking out the API and seeing that `toBinaryString` returns a string I'm convinced my solution should work but it does not.

My Solution:

```
String str = "5 in binary: ";
str.concat(Integer.toBinaryString(5));
```

or

```
String str = "5 in binary: ";
str + Integer.toBinaryString(5);
```

Each of these will just print out the original string "5 in binary: " rather than "5 in binary: 0101".

`toBinaryString()` returns a String value so this should be possible should it not?

Comment: Strings are immutable, so str.concat() does not modify str, it creates a new String instance, which gets thrown away because it is not assigned to anything.

Answer (score 4):

Because String is immutable object.
So `str + Integer.toBinaryString(5);` does not change the content of `str`. It just returns another String object. You need to assign that new object to `str` something like that:

```
str = str + Integer.toBinaryString(5);
```